# Classifying irreducible real representations

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and say $V$ is an irreducible representation over $\mathbb{R}$. Then $End_G(V) = End_{\mathbb{R}[G]}(V)$ must be a division algebra, since $V$ is a simple $\mathbb{R}[G]$-module. But division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are just $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}$. Apparently, the following is true:

- $End(V)\cong\mathbb{R} \Leftrightarrow V\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ is an irreducible complex representation.
- $End(V)\cong\mathbb{C} \Leftrightarrow V\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ is a direct sum of two non-isomorphic complex representations.
- $End(V)\cong\mathbb{H} \Leftrightarrow V\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ is a direct sum of two isomorphic complex representations.

Could someone explain why these are true, or provide further literature on irreducible real representations? Thanks!

Comment: This is discussed in section 13.2 of Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*.